# injective hull as the "topological dual to the completion"

Tags: commutative-algebra, injective-module

Dmitry Kaledin's [notes](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~kaledin/noc/index.html)
(Russian) on cohomology of sheaves on algebraic varieties define (lecture 14) the
injective hull of the residue field $k$ of a local ring $R$ as an
injective module $I$ such that

1. its support is the maximal ideal $\mathbb{m}$
2. $\mathrm{Hom}(k, I) = k$

Question: is this definition equivalent to the standard one with
[essential injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_extension)  (specialized to residue fields, of course)?

Further, the injective hull in this sense is explicitly described, if $R$ contains $k$, as the "topological dual of the completion" of $R$, $\varinjlim \mathrm{Hom}_k(R/\mathbb{m}^n, k)$ (note that the homomorphisms are taken over $k$!). While one can check that this is indeed an injective module, I wonder if it is an injective hull of $k=R/\mathbb{m}$ in the sense of the "essential injection definition".

Comment: Hrm... if so, then what resemblance does the flat cover bear to the completion?

Comment: @rschwieb only metaphorical, I think

Comment: Bordering on a Zen kōan perhaps?